# Switchee with 4 segments?

Tags: switchee

I need to switch on 4 segments.  I'm a little confused.

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}       
{case value="#^P(\\\\d+)$#|''"} 
         Show all categories
{/case}
    {case default="Yes"}
        {switchee variable="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}

            {case value="#^P(\\\\d+)$#|''"} 
            Show a specific category
            {/case}

            {case default="Yes"} 
            Show a specific sub-categories entries
            {/case}

            <!-- I need a fourth segment -->
            {case default="Yes"} 
            Show a specific product
            {/case}
            <!-- I need a fourth segment -->

        {/switchee}  
    {/case}  
{/exp:switchee}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try and start on the 4th segment then work your way back thru the segments using switchee. As it stands segment 2 will always be true (not sure what your regex is testing for though) pagination ?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
{case value="#^P(\\\\d+)$#|''"} 
Show all categories
{/case}

{case default="Yes"}

    {switchee variable="{segment_3}" parse="inward"}

        {case value="#^P(\\\\d+)$#|''"} 
        Show main category
        {/case}

        {case default="Yes"} 

            {switchee variable="{segment_4}" parse="inward"}

                {case value="#^P(\\\\d+)$#|''"} 
                Show subcategory products
                {/case}

                {case default="Yes"} 
                Show product
                {/case}

            {/switchee}

        {/case}

    {/switchee}

{/case} {/exp:switchee}
```